# Would the tmux process in ssh terminal be stopped when I terminate my laptop?

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux

I've known that the tmux process would shut down when I reboot my computer.
But is it also the same when the tmux process has been doing at ssh server?

For now, I've been downloading some data into that ssh server using tmux.
I've checked that the tmux process has been working though I get out ssh server and terminate the terminal window. 
But I'm wondering that whether I could terminate my laptop or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your laptop and your server are two different computers, then a reboot of your laptop will not terminate the tmux session you have running on your server. You can just detach at any time and reconnect later.